# How to quit the browser-sync server, or how to know the running server pid

Tags: browser-sync

do you know `browser-sync` have to provide any API to quit server?
I use `bs.exit ()` just quit automatically reload.
Or have any way to know the current server PID, I can manually kill it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

haha. I have solved it.

Put the server code into a js file, using the `child_process.fork` to run, you can get the child process pid